# Классы TextField и Required являются deprecated во Flask. Как исправить код?

Tags: python, python-2.x, flask

Изучаю flask по статьям с хабра. По примеру написал такой блок кода:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import Required

class LoginFrom(Form):
    openid = TextField('openid', validators=[Required()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

PyCharm подсказывает, что классы TextField и Required являются deprecated. Как исправить код ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextField заменить на StringField, а Required на DataRequired.

[What’s New in WTForms 3: Deprecated API’s](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html#deprecated-api-s)